# Unable to resolve host domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

Recently, I noticed that **time to time** my client is unable to resolve my domain name. I have a Lightsail instance with a static IP, a Lightsail DNS Zone, and finally a Route53 domain name.

The only thing I did for now is adding the Lightsail DNS Zone name servers to the Route53 registered domain name servers list (as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-name-servers-glue-records.html#domain-name-servers-glue-records-adding-changing)). I currently don't have hosted zone on Route53.

I have three questions. First, is the other way around more scalable? meaning, should I have a hosted zone on Route53 pointing Lightsail static IP (like [this](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-using-route-53-to-point-a-domain-to-an-instance)). Second, Is there a domain name access quota that I'm not aware of? and finally, Is there something flagrant that I'm doing wrong (I'm a newbie in networking).

### Edit

As mentioned in the comments, if someone could help me check if the public records are setup correctly or tell me how to do it, that would be great

Domain name: yimaru.services

Static IP address: 3.121.169.168

Comment: Someone who knows Lightsail will hopefully be able to help. If you want someone to take a look at your DNS records you could edit your question to include your domain name and IP address, so we can check public records to see if it's set up correctly.

Comment: please show what commands have you tried.

Comment: @JohnGreene I did everything with the AWS interface like mentioned in the tutorials